# Azure Service Fabric: Where is the port for my cluster?

Tags: azure, port, azure-service-fabric, azure-load-balancer

I was using SoapUI to hit an Azure Service Fabric service, but I was using the Client connection endpoint for my cluster. I suspected I was hitting the wrong port due to this error:

```
Error getting response; org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
```

**Where do I find the port for my cluster?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do I find the port for my cluster?

1) The port may be found in the `ServiceManifest.xml` file:

```
<Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="1234" />
```

2) The port may also be found in the Azure portal: load balancer > Frontend IP configuration > LBAppRule > Port

[image: Port in Azure portal]